# Prevent :EXPORT_LATEX_HEADER: in a subtree from overriding all buffer #+LATEX_ lines

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

Possibly a bug: When using `:EXPORT_LATEX_HEADER:` in a subtree's `:PROPERTIES:` it overrides all the buffer-level `#+LATEX_HEADER:` commands as well as everything given in an external file with `#+SETUPFILE:`.

So when having something like:

```
#+SETUPFILE: setup.org
#+LATEX_HEADER: \command1

* Headline
  :PROPERTIES:
  :EXPORT_LATEX_HEADER: \command2
  :END:
```

All you get in the exported .tex file is `\command2` in the header, without `\command1` and nothing from the setup file. Feature or bug, and if feature, how to unfeature it?

Comment: Interesting, I'd write to Org mailing list to ask about it. Most likely this wasn't intended.

Comment: @wvxvw I agree, I don't even see the sense of making it optional and certainly not default. I consider going `org-submit-bug-report`, getting into the mailing list is a bit too much for me at the moment.

Comment: It's the case if one is using babel header arguments as well. In your case I have trouble understanding why you would want to insert a latex header in a subtree. Wouldn't  it work at the top level?

Comment: @DJJ When having a file of one project where different pdf's need to be exported (using the export subtree feature), it's quite reasonable that particular files would need particular modifications. In my case for example I'd like to tweak the title. I think it's counterintuitive that all top level settings are ignored instead of being inherited.
The thing is made worse by the fact that a setupfile can only be loaded top-level with `#+SETUPFILE:` (no `:EXPORT_SETUP_FILE:`), so it's not even possible to define local setup files for each subtree.